# Issue in my SSL certificate When I try to connect with Pusher service

Tags: php, windows, ssl-certificate, pusher

I need help with resolving an issue related to SSL certificates on my Windows system. The problem surfaced when I attempted to connect to the Pusher service while building a chat feature for my Laravel project. I am unsure about the exact steps I should take to resolve this issue.

and this is the issue:

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

in The SSL cretificate